# Remove "Next Post" in nav_menu

Tags: menus

I am creating my custom navigation menu with background-images. The menu items have a title from the Page, and that title is displayed above my background image, which is not what I want because the image itself already contains the link text.

```
/* menu items */
function nav_menu_items($classes, $item) {
     $classes[] = "item-". $item->attr_title; 
     return $classes;
} 
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'nav_menu_items', 10,2);

.item-myitem a {
background: url(someimage);
text-decoration: none;
width: 20px;
}
```

However in the HTML it is displayed as (background-image is OK)

```
<a title="myitem" href="someurl">Next Post</a>
```

How do I remove that "Next Post"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with CSS text-indent: [`text-indent:-9000px;`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-indent.asp). That way your text is still there for accessibility.

Comment: Not working :(.

Comment: @hajder maybe post what you tried, show an example? i'm not going to guess what your mistake may have been.

Comment: I did what you suggested. Here's an image <img src="http://postimage.org/image/p2a7k2xf7/"> . It is not very visible in the screenshot, but there's an image behind "Truppen", you can also see that in the CSS editor.

Comment: @hajder If the a element is inline, you need to make it block or inline-block for text-indent to effect it - http://jsfiddle.net/tXZpK/.